# Comparing user-input CAPTCHA value against expected value stored in session

Tags: php, forms, captcha

I'm trying to implement a simple captcha into a form I'm building but I've run up against an issue I can't seem to sort out by myself.

I'm using simple code to generate a random number like so ....

```
$randomnr = rand(1000, 9999);
$_SESSION['randomnr2'] = md5($randomnr);
```

.... and then some more code to generate an image of the random number and display it on the page. I'm against it for validity like this ....

```
if (strlen($captcha) !== ($_SESSION['randomnr2'])) { 
    $error['captcha'] = "CAPTCHA error. Please try again";
}
```

How do I go about checking the value that's been input into the captcha input field against the random number that's stored in the session `randomnr2`?

Comment: Woo Wooo Wooo! That's not how captcha works. You don't check for the length but the actual content of the two strings. As for your second issue, don't have an id="captch" have an <input name="captcha" />, preferably the input field he's typing in to fill the captcha.

Comment: You're hashing the value of $randomnr that you're storing in session... you should also be hashing the value of $captcha and comparing the two hash values

Comment: @Khez - yes, sorry about that. It's not the length I should be checking - it's the the content :) Thanks for that. And from an answer below I see that I should be using 'int' instead. The input field has both terms <input type="text" name="captcha" id="captcha"/ >. Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: @Mark Thanks for your reply. That makes a hell of a lot of sense. Could you explain to me how to go about hashing the value of the input field?

Comment: @Mark @Jerry if I understand the app corectly you're showing in the captch the hash, meaning no re-hash of the user input is needed. P.S. an md5 is a very long captcha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are checking the length of the string against an md5 hash of the string here, but assuming `$captcha` is the number from the user, you can just do this:

```
if(md5($captcha) !== $_SESSION['randomnr2']) {
  $error['captcha'] = "CAPTCHA error. Please try again";
}
```

Comment: Thanks man but it doesn't work. What I'm trying to do is determine whether the VALUE - not strlen - that is stored in the '$captcha' variable matched the hashed random number. The variable is determined as follows ..... $captcha = $_POST['captcha'];' where captcha is the user input field on the form - <input type=text name=captcha />. I realise I'm probably going to have to take a different approach - because this isn't safe as another helpful soul pointed out - but it will still really help me if I can learn how to do this - if it can be done. Can that value be compared the the hashed number?

Comment: Let me see, the code you wrote above says "if the hashed variable 'captcha' is NOT equal to the hashed number stored in session 'randomnr2' return the error variable ..... is that right? That should work for me then ... but it doesn't :(

Comment: it does work. My apologies and thank you very much for this nugget of information GSto. Idiot that I am I changed the captcha script earlier today and deleted the part where the random number got stored in the session - I was trying just to get the raw numbers to match. Anyway, since there was no session with the stored value it was never going to work but now there is and it works like a charm. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

PHP will auto-convert anything to a string (if it can) for `strlen()`, so

```
echo strlen(42); 
echo strlen('42');
```

will both output '2', even though the first one's an integer. To compare the submitted value to the store value, it's as simple as

```
if ($_SESSION['randomnr2'] === (int)$captcha) {
   ... it matched ...
}
```

You'll want to cast the submitted value to an int again, as anything in the PHP $_GET/POST arrays is internally treated as a string.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mark. The way I have things set up buddy is that I more or less have to check it this way ... If the content of input field "captcha" does NOT match the stored hashed number, then display "try again" else continue ......

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id='captcha_to_show' style='border:1px solid silver;'>gobldeygook</div>
<input name='captcha' id='captcha'>
```

...

attached via scriptmonkey...

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  $('#captcha').val($('#captcha_to_show').html());
});
```

look into a open-source captcha script. your implementation is going to require sending that captcha across the page in a way that it's value can be seen by whatever is pulling the page, and that person/bot/whatever can fill in the validating field accordingly, so you actually have zero protection. that is why captchas either use convoluted images that are hard to impossible to read with a script, or semantic questions better understood by humans in context than bots, such as ['What would you say the sum of one and 3 are?' === 4]. and yes, the more simple image captcha's with the set fonts, spacing and size can be hacked with a sort of pixel-pattern dictionary attack.